# PHP как прикрепить файлы в массиве к другим полям формы

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте всем!

Интересует такое решение задачки. Имеется вот такой вот HTML код

```
    <input type="text" name="comp" placeholder="Comp" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="name1" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="desc[]" placeholder="desc1" /><br>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple /><br>

    <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="name2" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="desc[]" placeholder="desc2" /><br>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple /><br>
```

Как создать массив с названиями файлов которые были выбраны в первом или втором input. Имеется скрипт практически рабочий, но имеет дефект, что вместо названия файла имеется иероглиф

```
                $this_is_it = array();
                $post = array_values($_POST);
                        for($j = 0; $j < count($post[1]); $j++){
                            for($u = 0; $u < count($post[3]); $u++){
                                $this_is_it['order_' . ($j + 1)] = array(
                                    'name'   => $post[1][$j],
                                    'desc'   => $post[2][$j],
                                    'attach' => $post[3][$j]
                                );

                            }

                        }
```

Выводит он при этом:

```
array(2) { ["order_1"]=> array(3) { 
["name"]=> string(4) "lala" 
["desc"]=> string(7) "lalalal" 
["attach"]=> string(1) "�" } 
                    ["order_2"]=> array(3) { 
["name"]=> string(5) "name2" 
["desc"]=> string(5) "desc2" 
["attach"]=> string(1) "�" } }
```

Что делать, как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фрагмент кода, правильный, но он не учитывает множественный выбор файлов. Еще по ходу обсуждения выяснилось, что блоки будут добавляться динамически, вот решение (в виде отдельного файла

```
<?php
for ($i=1;$i<=$_POST['quantity'];$i++) {

    $orders['order_'.$i]['name']=$_POST['name'.$i];
    $orders['order_'.$i]['desc']=$_POST['desc'.$i];
    $orders['order_'.$i]['files']=$_POST['files'.$i];
}
//print_r($orders);
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="comp" placeholder="Comp" /><br>
<input type="text" name="name1" placeholder="name1" /><br>
<input type="text" name="desc1" placeholder="desc1" /><br>
<input type="file" name="files1[]" multiple /><br>


<input type="text" name="name2" placeholder="name2" /><br>
<input type="text" name="desc2" placeholder="desc2" /><br>
<input type="file" name="files2[]" multiple /><br>

<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="2" /><br>
```

По событию JS добавляется еще блок ввода данных и к input type="hidden" name="quantity" value=" добавляется 1 и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению я это знаю и это не совсем то что мне нужно. Понимаете, мне нужно получить такую конструкцию, чтобы при отправке формы файлы из первого инпута прикреплялись к первым 2 инпитам, а соответственно файлы из второго ко вторым инпутам и причем эти инпуты можно было хоть сколько угодно добавлять. Вот в чем сложности, если знаете ответ на мой вопрос то пожалуйста дайте мне на него ответ.

Comment: Так они и прикрепляются, ["attach"] в каком нужен виде, при условии что файлов несколько? Обработка формы просто какая то странная, не проще бы разбить по именам и все обрабатывать. и вот это  multiple - означает что можно несколько файлов подцепить, вам несколько надо или 1 в каждой форме?

Comment: Смотрите, в вашем случае если выбрано 2 файла - то в массив передается только один. И Ваш код, хоть и странноватый, но у меня работает http://prntscr.com/ecpou6 - поэтому посмотрите у себя кодировку файла, она должна быть UTF-8 без BOM

Comment: Было бы вообще отлично если в ["attach"] я бы видел названия файлов желательно через ",", но это я и сам смогу сделать. Просто через var_dump я вижу картину с иероглифом а не названия файлов, а насчет формы, я сейчас занимаюсь разработкой данной системы и сделал все на скоряк, на моем нормальном сайте все будет нормально. Просто я бы хотел получить цивилизованный ответ на мой вопрос, т.к. я сам уже ничего придумать не могу, голова просто кипит.

Comment: У меня все нормально работает, кодировка файла у Вас - как я указал выше?

Comment: Еще у вас в каждой форме добавленно по 2 файла или в каждой по 1 файлу и да такой способ я проверял, но он дает названия всех файлов в массиве и тогда всплывает тот же вопрос как их распределить по формам?

Comment: Да кодировка UTF-8 без BOM

Comment: Для файлов мультивыбор нужен или нет? Формы будут статические или динамические (подгружаться по клику jquery например) ?

Comment: Нужен мултивыбор, формы должны быть динамические, да именно по клику, но скорее всего не jquery a javascript, но это на сколько я понимаю разницы не имеет

Comment: Вот распределение по формам http://pastebin.com/Gqrj493u , проверьте этот файлик отдельно - будут ли иероглифы с именами. Суть такая - в начале 1 форма ввода и скрытое поле quantity=1, когда добавляете по клику еще блок, добавляете к значению еще 1, чтобы скрипт обработки знал сколько раз ему прокручивать.

Comment: По моему все работает, но только 1 файл работает в массиве как ключ  а второй как значение http://prnt.sc/ecpy1p

Comment: Не, нажмите Ctrl+U  и увидите стуктуру. Она такая http://prntscr.com/ecpyon

Comment: Спасибо вам большое очень меня выручили, а то я бы еще сидел и сидел. Еще один вопросик чтобы мне теперь вывести названия из массива мне нужно использовать цикл foreach?

Comment: Да, foreach ($orders as $order) {  и т.д. Я заменю сейчас поле Ответ, если Вы считатете что оно правильное - отметьте его как решенное.